# Child elements not being rendered in the DOM

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm iterating through an array of objects to create elements in the `Navbar`.

While the program runs, I do not see these elements being rendered in the DOM and I'm not sure why.

This is what I have:

```
// data.json
{
  "navbar": {
    "navBrand": "My Name",
    "navItems": [
      {
        "name": "Bio",
        "href": "#bio"
      },
      {
        "name": "Projects",
        "href": "#projects"
      },
      {
        "name": "Articles",
        "href": "#articles"
      },
      {
        "name": "Resume",
        "href": "#resume"
      },
      {
        "name": "Contact",
        "href": "#contact"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
// Navigation.tsx
// Bootstrap imports
import { Container, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

// Component imports
import NavigationItem from './NavigationItem';

// Import data
import data from '../../data/data.json';

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg='light'>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand>{data.navbar.navBrand}</Navbar.Brand>
        { data.navbar.navItems.forEach(navItem => {
          <NavigationItem {...navItem} />
        })}
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

```
// NavigationItem.tsx
const NavigationItem = (props: {name: string, href: string }): JSX.Element => {
  return <a href={props.href}>{props.name}</a>;
};

export default NavigationItem;
```

I've also tried:

```
// Navigation.tsx
return <NavigationItem {...navItem} />
```

Also, doing this prints out the array objects one at a time:

```
// Navigation.tsx
{ data.navbar.navItems.forEach(navItem => {
  console.log(navItem);
  // <NavigationItem {...navItem} />
})}

// Results
[Log] {name: "Bio", href: "#bio"} (bundle.js, line 627)
[Log] {name: "Projects", href: "#projects"} (bundle.js, line 627)
[Log] {name: "Articles", href: "#articles"} (bundle.js, line 627)
[Log] {name: "Resume", href: "#resume"} (bundle.js, line 627)
[Log] {name: "Contact", href: "#contact"} (bundle.js, line 627)
```

Adding just a simple `console.log('Test')` inside of the `NavigationItem` function never prints out anything, so seems like data isn't flowing into it.

So two questions:

1. Why wouldn't this be working?
2. If you need to iterate through an array to generate elements, should the child component be in the iteration, or should the iteration happen inside of the child component?

Comment: Try using ```map``` instead of ```forEach```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpouse for using `.map()` is that it returns an array, on the other hand, `.forEach()` doesn't return anything.
Also its good to be considered that these components should have a `key`...

```
data.navbar.navItems.map((currentNavItem) => {
// depends of your data structure
  return <NavigationItem {...currentNavItem} />
});
```

Comment: would be helpful to provide an explanation as to why, also, you need to get rid of those brackets in your callback or use the return keyword

Comment: The main purpouse for using `.map()` is that it returns an array, on the other hand, `.forEach()` doesn't return anything... Also its good to be considered that these components should have a `key`...

Comment: The explanation should be in the answer not in a comment. Code only answers are not well received here

Comment: Okay, thank you for the guidance, ill edit it.